# How to correctly load XML files on mobile devices using unity3d

Tags: android, ios, xml, unity-game-engine

I have some level definitions in xml format (with .txt extension) inside (without any subfolders) my project's rescources folder

I for more scalability, I have a plain text file naming all these level definition XMLs

I read that file using

```
TextAsset WorldList = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("WorldList");
```

And then I load the needed world:

```
TextAsset TA = (TextAsset)Resources.Load(/*"LevelDefs/" +*/ Worlds[worldToload]);
xps.parseXml(TA.text);
loadLevel(levelToLoad);
```

(you see that I have moved these rescources out of subfolder to reduce the chance of them not loading)
worldToload here is the index number of that world

program works fine on windows but nothing loads on my android test device.
I seem to have problems debugging on device so I only guess something went wrong in loading phase.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David I have resolved this problem.
for more precision I add some small details:
1-As David points out in his answer (and as stated in unity documentations), we should use StreamingAssets  if we want to have the same folder structure. One should use `Application.streamingAssetsPath`to retrieve the path.

However, files are still in the apk package in android's case, so they should be accessed using unity android's www class.

a good practice here is to create a method to read the file (even mandatory if you are going to read more than one file)

here is one such method:

```
private IEnumerator LoadDataFromResources(string v)
{
    WWW fileInfo = new WWW(v); 
    yield return fileInfo;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileInfo.error))
    {
        fileContents = fileInfo.text;
    }
    else
        fileContents = fileInfo.error;
}
```

This is a coroutine, and to use it we need to call it using

```
yield return StartCoroutine(LoadDataFromResources(path + "/fileName.ext"));
```

Yet another remark: we can not write into this file or modify it as it's still inside the apk package.

Answer (score 2):

From Unity Documentation:

> Most assets in Unity are combined into the project when it is built.
>   However, it is sometimes useful to place files into the normal
>   filesystem on the target machine to make them accessible via a
>   pathname. An example of this is the deployment of a movie file on iOS
>   devices; the original movie file must be available from a location in
>   the filesystem to be played by the PlayMovie function.
>
> Any files placed in a folder called **StreamingAssets** in a Unity project
>   will be copied **verbatim** to a particular folder on the target machine.
>   You can retrieve the folder using the **Application.streamingAssetsPath**
>   property. It’s always best to use Application.streamingAssetsPath to
>   get the location of the StreamingAssets folder, it will always point
>   to the correct location on the platform where the application is
>   running.

So below snippet should work:

```
// Put your file to "YOUR_UNITY_PROJ/Assets/StreamingAssets"
// example: "YOUR_UNITY_PROJ/Assets/StreamingAssets/Your.xml"

if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
{
  // Android
  string oriPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Your.xml");

  // Android only use WWW to read file
  WWW reader = new WWW(oriPath);
  while ( ! reader.isDone) {}

  realPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Your"; // no extension ".xml"
  var contents = System.IO.File.ReadAll(realPath);
}
else // e.g. iOS
{      
  dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Your.xml");
}
```

Comment: Great idea... thanks for the tip... Though it hasn't solved my problem yet... restructured the code and folders/files but still can not load the file.